# Add Text to file when performing Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I've been looking around trying to solve this issue but nothing has worked so far.
I am wanting to pick 1/multiple files, add a hardcoded value (e.g `` "DIAB`r`n" ``) to the start of the file content and then write to another volume.
Do I have to do multiple statements or is it something I can do in one.
What I have so far is try using 2 statements:

```
# Find the file/s .HL7, move to a new destination and change the filename to add "DIAB-"
# to the front - this is working
Get-ChildItem -Path $DiabetesPath |
    Where-Object { (!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -like "*.HL7") } |
    Move-Item -Destination $DestinationPath -PassThru |
    Rename-Item -NewName {"DIAB-" + $_.Name}

# this is what is not working - after files moved to destination trying to add some text
# to the start of the file content
Get-ChildItem $DestinationPath -Recurse -Filter DIAB*.HL7 | ForEach-Object
{
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName 
    Set-Content $_.FullName -Value "DIAB`r`n", $content 
}
```

When I try it, it says:

```
cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 2
Supply values for the following parameters
process[0]:
```

When I enter something it keeps going:

```
process[1]:
process[2]:
...
```

Not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Wow! didn't realise the position of `{` would affect anything.

Moved the `{` next to the `ForEach-Object` and it works.

```
Get-ChildItem $DestinationPath -Recurse -Filter DIAB*.HL7 | ForEach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName 
    Set-Content $_.FullName -Value "DIAB`r`n", $content 
}
```